# Single Pole or Multiple Pole Safety Disconnect Switch

Tags: safety-switch

I am taking power from a L5-30 receptacle and using it to power a large load. I want to add a safety disconnect switch as shown below between the receptacle and the load. Since the L5-30 circuit is single phase, is it sufficient to use a single pole switch or should I use a 3-pole switch to fully isolate the hot, neutral and ground? [image]

Comment: Cheap Cheese safety switches are a contradiction in terms.

Answer (score 2):

Unless the supply is suspect, just the hot should do.

If it's cord and plug connected (which your question pretty much states by identifying a receptacle as what feeds it) you can always unplug it if you feel a need for even more separation.